# Send mail from a client side, standalone program

Tags: sockets, email, smtp

Is it possible to make a standalone program (e.g. in c++) that is able to send emails without needing to send it to a server? In other words you only enter the adresses in the program and it's not needed to send them to a server or third party.
I am aware of the three way handshake that is needed in order to establish a connection via sockets. Yet can one "attach" a SMTP to the program, or integrate it in any way? 
(And if you can how do most internet providers handle these?)

Edit:

I would like to create such a program as a friend who runs a business was talking about him having to trust companies with those adresses. If you can create a client side application where the email adresses stay at the client side only (not getting in hands of third parties) then I'd like to take a look at that.

Comment: Do you want to make it for fun/learning, or you simply need one? What do you mean by "send it to a server"? Directly establishing a connection with the recipient, without any SMTP relay?

Answer (score 2):

An SMTP server is required in order to send an email (unless you use MAPI, in which case you send the email to a MAPI provider, such as Outlook/Exchange, which then delivers the email as needed).  The question is, WHICH server to use.  Due to anti-spam security measures, it is best to send your email through your company/ISP's SMTP server and let it relay to the destination recipients as needed.

However, it is possible to relay manually (though this is less likely to succeed and more likely to get you blacklisted).  Extract the domain portion of a given email address, perform a DNS query to retrieve that domain's MX record(s), then connect to each reported SMTP server and send your email to it, trying each server on at a time until one of them is successful.